# Control Observables with pipes

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way to handle this bit of code

```
return new Observable(subscriber => {
    let subscription = this.anotherObservable().subscribe(
        (next) => {
            if (this.condition1(next)) {
                subscriber.next(next);
            } else if (this.condition2(next)) {
                subscriber.complete();
            } else {
                subscriber.error('there was an error');
            }
        },
        (error) => subscriber.error(error),
        () => subscriber.complete()
    );

    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
});
```

This code is inside a method in a class.

The `anotherObservable` returns an Observable that emit different type of data that's why `condition1` and `condition2` are boolean based on the `next` value.

My question is, am I missing some operators combinations that could handle this Observable with the same behavior but using pipes instead of rewriting a "custom" Observable?

Comment: Looks to me like a `takeUntil` operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/takeuntil.html

Comment: Thanks @cgTag, unless I'm missing something `takeUntil` cannot filter with a boolean?

Comment: `takeUtil` keeps emitting until an observable emits a value. So just apply a filter to only emit until the condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a combination of takeWhile and flatMap:

```ts
const subscription = anotherObservable.pipe(
      takeWhile(someValue => !this.condition2(someValue)),
      flatMap(someValue => {
        if(this.condition1(someValue)) {
          return of(someValue);
        }
        return throwError('there was an error');
      })
    ).subscribe(someValue => //do something with value);
```

Comment: I feel like this is kinda going to work but not entirely, shouldn't `takeWhile` do something with `condition1` too?

Comment: i dont think so. 
If anotherObservable completes, the stream should complete.
If Condition2 is true, the stream completes.
If Condition1 is true, the value gets passed through the pipe and if Condition1 is false, it throws an Error.
As long as is don't miss something, it should do exactly the same as your codesnippet. What issue do you have?

Comment: they do not behave the same if both, condition1 and condition2 can be true for the same input. in this case your snippet will pass through the value, my snipped will complete the stream since the takeWhile is used before the flatMap.

Comment: Just for the records, I'm with `rxjs: 5.5.4` so I had to use `return new ErrorObservable('there was an error');` instead of `throwError `

Comment: @PeterPan666 Be aware than if you `throwError`there is no recovering from that. Your observable will be completed. It is common to use a second observable (usually a subject) that handles the error side of things, so that the original observable can continue to listen for results

Comment: Thanks, in my case I really need to terminate it so it's perfect for my use case this way ;)